# Does this quadratic form represent 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratic-forms

I am stuck on the following question in Lam's quadratic forms for a few days now.  Let $a,b,c$ be three elements of a field $F$ such that $0 \neq a^2+b^2 \neq c^2$.  Show that the quadratic form $\langle a^2+b^2, a^2 +b^2 - c^2 \rangle$ represents 1.  In general, how does one determine if a quadratic form determines 1 or not?

Comment: what page???????????

Comment: Chapter 1, problem 21, page 24

Comment: Your question "in general" is Corollary 3.5 on page 11, First representation Theorem, with $d \in \dot{F},$ then $d \in D(q)$ if and only if $q \perp \langle -d \rangle$ is isotropic.

Comment: Finish with Witt's Chain Equivalence theorem.